# Formatting excel with importexcel in PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I've been trying to figure out how the Set-CellStyle works in ImportExcel: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

I have imported excel file with Import-Excel, saved it to variable and made some changes to it. Now I am trying to export it along with some formatting. What I am trying to do is to change the cell color in this area: rows 1-4 and from columns A to D.

If I look Get-Help Set-CellStyle it says:

```
SYNTAX
    Set-CellStyle [[-WorkSheet] <Object>] [[-Row] <Object>] [[-LastColumn] <Object>] [[-Pattern] {None | Solid | DarkGray | MediumGray | LightGray | Gray125 | Gray0625 | DarkVertical | DarkHorizontal | DarkDown | DarkUp | DarkGrid | DarkTrellis | LightVertical | LightHorizontal | LightDown | LightUp | LightGrid | LightTrellis}] [[-Color] <Color>]
```

Here's what I am basically doing:

```
$Excel = Import-Excel -Path C:\Temp\excel.xlsx
$Excel | Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\excel.xlsx -Autosize | Set-CellStyle ??
```

But I just can't seem to get the Set-CellStyle to work. I just don't understand the right syntax, and the help file or the examples at github are not very clear. Could somebody help me to figure this out?

Also, if anyone know how to bold particular rows/cells please share an example :)

Answer (score 0):

[The code for the function is here](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/Set-CellStyle.ps1).

All you'd need to do is pass the row number and last column. It starts from column `A` by default. You cannot use in the pipeline like in your question as it does not accept values from pipeline.

```
$Excel = Import-Excel -Path C:\Temp\excel.xlsx
$Excel | Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\excel.xlsx -Autosize

# figure out how to assign a worksheet,  e.g. to variable $ws

# loop over rows
foreach($row in 1./4){
    Set-CellStyle -Worksheet $ws -Row $row -LastColumn "D"
}
```

Comment: How can the `-FirstColumn` be specified? There appears no parameter for first column. Can it no be done?

Comment: It can't be done the way it's written at the moment. To do it, manually add `$FirstColumn` to param, and replace `A` on line 13 with `$FirstColumn`. So you change `"A$($Row):$($LastColumn)$($Row)"` to `"$FirstColumn$($Row):$($LastColumn)$($Row)"`.